# Error "name: 'Predictions' is not defined when using a confusion matrix

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

I'm getting the error while running:

## Creating a confusion matrix   ##option

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,predictions))
```

Error: NameError: name 'predictions' is not defined

The entire code is:

## Importing libraries

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


# Importing the dataset
loans = pd.read_csv('loan_borowwer_data.csv')
loans.describe()


loans.isnull().sum()


loans.info()


plt.hist(loans['fico'],color='blue',edgecolor='white',bins=5)
plt.title('Histogram of fico')

plt.xlabel('fico')
plt.ylabel('frequency')
plt.show()




plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
loans[loans['not.fully.paid']==1]['fico'].hist(alpha=0.5,color='blue', bins=30,label='not.fully.paid=1')
loans[loans['not.fully.paid']==0]['fico'].hist(alpha=0.5,color='red', bins=30,label='not.fully.paid=0')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('FICO')



#Create a list of elements containing the string purpose. Name this list cat_feats.
cat_feats = ['purpose']



final_data = pd.get_dummies(loans,columns=cat_feats,drop_first=True)
final_data.info()



final_data.head()


# # Train-Test Split

# In[ ]:







X = final_data.drop('not.fully.paid',axis=1)
y = final_data['not.fully.paid']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=101)


# # Training Decision Tree Model
# Let us create a DecisionTreeClassifier from sklearn.tree.

# In[76]:


#Let us create a DecisionTreeClassifier from sklearn.tree.


# In[77]:


# Decision tree model
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtree.fit(X_train,y_train)


# # Evaluating Decision Tree


# Creating a confusion matrix   ##option
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,predictions))

NameError: name 'predictions' is not defined
```

Please help

Comment: As the code says, you never defined the variable `predictions` and therefore can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a step before creating the confusion matrix. After you declare and `fit()` the model with the train data, you need to do a prediction on the test data. It would be something like `predictions = dtree.predict(X_test)` which will create the predicted y values for the X_test values. Once that is done, you can run the confusion matrix and it should create the matrix you desire. Hope this helps.